# Manhwa where a girl is adopted by a duke. The dukes eat a strange fruit to support the mansion

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

The female lead is a girl who was adopted by the duke along with another girl. The female lead was abused and being her maid she slept in the service room to attend to her sister. She was reborn and then adopted first by the duke, who had black hair. She fainted from the trauma and the duke gave her the main princess' room and a strange fruit that means she is part of the family, but at the moment of eating it, she fainted due to it looking like blood. This fruit is to allow them to support the mansion for a strange dark energy or something like that.

Comment: I made some edits based on my best guess of what you meant. Feel free to [edit] it back into shape if I misunderstood.

Comment: Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Comment: Was this other girl adopted (i.e. the duke adopted two girls), or is the other girl his daughter? It sounds like she was adopted to be a maid for his daughter - is that it? Second sentence says "ml was abused" but I see no other mention of ml - is that a typo of fl, i.e. the protagonist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is ***[A World Without You](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/a-world-without-you)***.

> After being taken in by the noble house of Nacht, Sienna grew up with her adopted sister, Lorena, who she believed to be the sweetest, kindest person in the world. But after Lorena attempts to kill her, Sienna realizes how much her "loving" sister actually hated her. She tries to end her life with a magic potion but ends up going back in time instead. Determined to survive, she tries to use her memories to her advantage. For some strange reason though... Lorena is now nowhere to be found.
>
> [image: Promotional art for "A World Without You."]

The female lead, Sienna, lived in an orphanage for children with magical aptitude, where she was subjected to physical and verbal abuse by the headmaster until she was adopted by the Grand Duke, Rodrik Nacht, who has black hair and two biological sons, Asiel and Mihael.

When Sienna arrives at the Duke's mansion, she meets Lorena Minanchy, an older girl from a noble family who was also adopted by the Duke. Lorena is outwardly sweet and charming towards Sienna, but uses deception to steal Sienna's magical power for herself. Sienna later ends up in prison, having been framed by Lorena, and commits suicide by drinking a vial of poison.

She then wakes up as her younger self back in the orphanage, on the day that she was adopted by the Duke in her previous life. She resists being adopted by the Duke this time, fainting in the process, but her plan fails and the Duke adopts her anyway.

When she arrives at the mansion, Lorena isn't there; in fact, there's no sign that she actually exists in this timeline, hence the manhwa's title. Sienna is given the lavish bedroom that was Lorena's room in her previous life, rather than the more modest room she slept in before, but doesn't feel comfortable there, so on the first night she secretly sleeps in her old room. She's subsequently brought back to the more lavish bedroom, but prefers to be in a smaller, adjoining bedroom for maids that isn't currently in use.

In chapter 12, Sienna is sat at a dining table with the Duke and his two sons when they're all served red pomegranates dripping with juice (one of them is pictured in the image above). This is said to be a custom when welcoming a new family member, but the fruit reminds Sienna of bleeding flesh and she faints again.

In chapter 23, Sienna learns that magicians who aren't part of the Nacht bloodline would normally be uncomfortable living in the family home. This effect could be temporarily suspended by the casting of a spell, but eating some of the pomegranate she was served before made Sienna recognised as part of the bloodline, meaning she can now live in the mansion comfortably by default.

You can read the full manhwa at [Tapas](https://tapas.io/series/a-world-without-you/info).